# jquery plugins in angular js stop working after routing to another partial and then back

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using maphilight on an image map in the first page of my app which works perfectly fine upon opening the app. However after clicking one of the areas and routing to a new page but then returning to the imagemap page via a "back to search" link or the browsers back arrow, the areas of the map no longer highlight on mouseover. After digging around a little I am thinking I might need to froce the page to reload or something like that? not sure how to accomplish this though. Thanks in advance for the feedback.

Maphilight Directive

```
myApp.directive('highlight', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: $(function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $('img[usemap]').maphilight();
    })};
});
```

Partial containing imagemap

```
<section class="artistinfo">
  <div class="artist cf">
    <h1>Select a room for more details</h1>
  <div class="info">
     <img ng-src="images/housediagram.jpg" alt="Photo of thing" class="map" usemap="#houseMap" highlight>

    <map name="houseMap" id="map">
      <area ng-repeat="room in rooms" name="{{room.name}}" id="{{room.id}}"  shape="poly" coords="{{room.coords}}" href="#/diagram/{{room.id}}" />
    </map>
   </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Controller for Imagemap partial

```
roomControllers.controller('DiagramController', ['$scope', '$timeout',  '$http', function($scope, $timeout, $http) {
 $http.get('js/master.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.rooms = data;

 });
}]);
```

Thanks a bunch in advance

Comment: shouldn't your directive's link function target the specific element rather than all? otherwise you're initializing them all n times where n is how many there are. (though i doubt fixing this would fix your problem, it would simply be more efficient)

Comment: if you are referring to the img[usemap] part then yes i believe i am supposed to put element instead however when i make this change, maphilight no longer works @KevinB